# pca.fit(X) return Error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, jupyter

guys.. I'm on some project that involve image data reduction.

And i'm suppose to use this the load the data. I'm already import the needed lib.

```
faces = pd.DataFrame([])
for file in os.listdir('dataset/'):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    if(file_extension in ['.pgm']):

        img = cv2.imread('dataset/'+ '/' + file)
        face = pd.Series(img.flatten(),name=file)
        faces = faces.append(face.fillna(0))
```

And right after I populate the data, I do data-splitting for train and test. like this.

```
X = []
y = []
for nameFolder in os.listdir('dataset/LEFT'):
    for file in os.listdir('dataset/LEFT/' + nameFolder):
        img = cv2.imread('dataset/LEFT/' + nameFolder + '/' + file )
        face = pd.Series(img.flatten(),name=file)
        X.append(face)
        y.append(nameFolder)
```

all that code above, still working fine. but the problem happen after that.
I want to used for `scaler` or `PCA`, but it give me some Error.

the rest below is about how i do my data-split, PCA, and scaler.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, train_label, test_label = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
```

Scaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
train_img = scaler.transform(X_train)
test_img = scaler.transform(test_img)
```

PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
faces_pca = PCA(n_components=2)
faces_pca.fit(X)
components = faces_pca.transform(X)
projected = faces_pca.inverse_transform(components)
```

and the error below shown, right on I'm using .fit():

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So now, I want asking. must I need change the data format or type or something? if yes, tell me must be like that, and how to be like that if possible. and next
If my data was ok, what i must do before, to make it possible to do some .fit() and finish the data using PCA or scaler.

Comment: I think the issue comes from your array X.        Can you try to print it ?

Comment: Did you search with the error message? - it should provide enough results to get you started.  You should always include the complete Traceback, formatted as code, in your question.

Comment: Does `X`'s shape meet the requirements in [the docs?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit)